# How to pass parametes to a function inside datatable which is binded using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am having a datatable which I am binding to data using ajax call. So inside that table one button is present which is having 2 parameters .But I am getting error on the button click saying save(a,b) not defined
my code is given below

```
      var Action='<a href="javascript:void(0)"title="Edit" id="opener"
 onclick="show('+data[i].GunId,data[i].UsingBranchId+)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>'
```

and my function is like

```
  show(a,b)
    {
******
*****
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code is shown below:

```
var Action = 
    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" id="opener"'
    + ' onclick="show(' + data[i].GunId + ',' + data[i].UsingBranchId + ')">'
    + '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>'
```